# Row/column is not a member of system.windows.form.datagridvie in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Row/column is not a member of system.windows.form.datagridvie in vb.net.
I am using below code datagridview.columns and datagridview.rows are  not member of grid. How export to Excel datagridview . And we can't use the dat source because in datagrid i hid some value using format function grid
For colIndex As Integer = 0 To dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
worksheet.Cells(1, colIndex + 1) = dataGridView.Columns(colIndex).HeaderText
Next

```
' Set the cell values
For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
    For colIndex As Integer = 0 To dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        worksheet.Cells(rowIndex + 2, colIndex + 1) = dataGridView.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex).Value
    Next
Next

' Save the Excel file
Dim saveFileDialog As New SaveFileDialog
```

I am trying export to Excel from datagrid using vb.net window application but property(rows/column)are not part of data grid member .

Comment: vb.net is case sensitive and not accept camelCase only PascalCase.

Comment: There are quite a number of 3rd party tools (via nugets among other sources). That make exporting data very elementary,  might be worth your time checking them

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily in vb.net, thanks for the assemblies.
First, VB.Net is case sensitive. Use Visual Studio or other editor, which provide automatic correction among a lot other services like debugging or text formatting.
Two assemblies provide the funcionality for what you want to achieve in the above question.

- **System.Windows.Forms**

this is to get DataGridView, and

- **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

which provide the Excel funcionality as you use an Office Excel application.
You have to make a reference to these two assemblies, and you can coding immediately.